# How to communicate Express API and React in separate Docker containers

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, express, nginx

I have a simple application that grabs data from express and displays it in react. It works as intended without docker, but not when launching them as containers. Both React and Express are able to launch and can be viewed in browser at localhost:3000 and localhost:5000 after running docker

**How they are communicating**

In the react-app package.json, I have
`"proxy": "http://localhost:5000"`
and a fetch to the express route.

**React Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:17 as build

WORKDIR /code

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

RUN npm run build

FROM nginx:1.12-alpine

COPY --from=build /code/build /usr/share/nginx/html

EXPOSE 80

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

**Express Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:17

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 5000

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3"
services:
  react-app:
    image: react
    stdin_open: true
    ports:
      - "3000:80"
    networks:
      - react-express
    
  api-server:
    image: express
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    networks:
      - react-express

networks:
  react-express:
    driver: bridge
```

Answer (score 1):

from your example I figured out that you are using react-scripts?

If so, proxy parametr works only for development for `npm start`.

> Keep in mind that proxy only has effect in development (with npm start), and it is up to you to ensure that URLs like /api/todos point to the right thing in production.

here: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/

Comment: I still have the issue when running the react dockerfile in a dev enviornment with npm start instead of build

Comment: Something like this?

`
FROM node:17 as build

WORKDIR /code

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["npm", "start"]
`

what error you get in console?

Comment: In the docker terminal--

Proxy error: Could not proxy request /logs from localhost:3000 to http://localhost:5000.
See https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors for more information (ECONNREFUSED).

In the webbrowser console--
GET http://localhost:3000/logs 500 (Internal Server Error)
Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token P in JSON at position 0

Comment: Finally, I get it, how it is called. I think in dev mode (npm start) you can use `api-server:5000` in proxy attribute in package.json.
But I would recommend using env variables for these cases. You can switch them for dev and production build.

Comment: http://api-server:5000 works in dev mode. I will try implementing env variables to have a working version of the production build

Comment: yes, try it. It is better solution and there is a lot of information about it. For example https://tacomanator.medium.com/environments-with-create-react-app-7b645312c09d

Answer (score 0):

Using a proxy in package.json does not work, so instead you can put this in your react app. The same Dockerfile and docker-compose setup is used.

```
  const api = axios.create({
    baseURL: "http://localhost:5000"
  })
```

and make request to express like this

```
api.post("/logs", {data:value})
    .then(res => {
      console.log(res)
    })
```

This may raise an error with CORS, so you can put this in your Express API in the same file that you set the port and have it listening.

```
import cors from 'cors'

const app = express();

app.use(cors({
    origin: 'http://localhost:3000'
}))
```